# No response on localhost from nodejs server

Tags: node.js, localhost

I have just begun with NodeJs and was trying a commonly found basic example of a server -

```
var http = require("http");
http.createServer(function(request, response) {
  response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
  response.write("Hello World");
  response.end();
}).listen(8888);
console.log('Hi there !');
```

Now when I run `node example.js` using `cmd`, I get the correct message `Hi there !`. However, when running on `localhost:8888` or `127.0.0.1:8888`, I get `This webpage is not available`.

I also have XAMPP installed but from what I know that uses port `80`.

Also my installation directory and my code directory is different. Is that causing a problem here ? Any help appreciated

Comment: What version of Node are you running? I just tested this code and it works perfectly for me. I'm guessing you're on a Windows box based on referencing cmd.

Comment: v0.10.11. I doubt there is a code issue. Some issue related to the configuration/settings I feel. Just not able to resolve

Comment: Current version is 0.10.30. Might be worth updating if possible, but this code is so simple I doubt that's it... The installation directory/code directory shouldn't matter at all in this case, because the http module is built into node. Maybe change the port number as well just in case something is grabbing that.

Comment: When you run the exact code posted just open a browser and go to that address (while the server is still running). is that what you're doing?

Comment: @rtucker88 Yeah version wasn't a problem.

Comment: @eshortie You were right. I was doing it after the server stopped. Sad. Thanks a ton for the tip !